# How do I increase the copy buffer size in tmux?

Tags: tmux

**Question**: How do I increase the copy-buffer size in tmux?

**Data**: When I run the following command...

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do echo "$i"; done
```

... and highlight the entire output in tmux (using either the mouse or keyboard commands), here is what gets sent to the system pasteboard:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
--snip--
205  
206  
207  
208  
20   (<--- Notice where it cuts off)
```

**Triage**:
- This persists when I quit tmux and kill the server, move tmux.conf and launch a fresh tmux instance with the default conf file. (Having to re-learn the default keys was difficult X_X).
- Also persists on a different machine (again, with default tmux settings) with the exact software (listed below).
- Also persists in default Terminal.app (again, with default tmux settings)

**System**:
    OS X 10.9.2
    tmux 1.9a (homebrew) + reattach-to-user-namespace (homebrew)
    iTerm Build 1.0.0.20140421

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I can't believe it's been over a year and no one else as responded.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tmux-copy-paste-on-os-x-a-better-future) I learned about the new `copy-pipe` command that [was added to tmux 1.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tmux/files/tmux/tmux-1.8/):

> `copy-pipe` mode command to copy selection and pipe the selection to a
>     command.

Changing your copy-mode bindings to use the new `copy-pipe` command fixed the problem for me:

```
# (from my tmux.conf)...
# Change copy / paste bindings to work like Vim
# Note this used to use `copy-selection` but that has been replaced
# with `copy-pipe` as of Tmux 1.8. See: https://goo.gl/ea3CRO
bind Escape copy-mode
bind p paste-buffer
bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"

# Update default binding of `Enter` to also use copy-pipe
unbind -t vi-copy Enter
bind-key -t vi-copy Enter copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. A few pointers.

1. `reattach-to-user-namespace` is not required. Just `pbcopy`.
2. Tested with `tmux 2.3`
3. The trick is to get the `MouseDragEnd1Pane` event to fire off `pbcopy`.
4. Use `iTerm2` which means that Mouse Support just works.
   From `tmux v2.1` only `set-option -g mouse on` is required.
5. You don't need vi-copy mode. Just make sure that the `MouseDragEnd1Pane` is bound as below

Here is my stripped down `~/.tmux.conf`

```
# --------------------------------
# Turn on the Mouse Support - defaults seem good
# --------------------------------
set-option -g mouse on
# when we finish "selecting" send it to pbcopy (and into the OS X buffer)
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"

# --------------------------------
# Use vim keybindings in copy mode
# --------------------------------
setw -g mode-keys vi

# Setup 'v' to begin selection as in Vim
# You enter with C-b [ and then "v" - then normal keypresses to "highlight"
# .. [Enter] or "y" will select (because of below bindings)
bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection
#
# 'y'ank will send the selection to the OS X buffer
bind-key -t vi-copy y            copy-pipe "pbcopy"

# --------------------------------
# Update default binding of `Enter` to also use Send the selection to OS X buffer
# --------------------------------
unbind   -t vi-copy Enter
bind-key -t vi-copy Enter        copy-pipe "pbcopy"

# selecting can now be done with
#  hilighting with a mouse
#  selecting with C-b [ v .. now vi mode for selecting text
#
# pasting  can now be done with
# ⌘ - V
# C-b ]
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to have worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24973743/35003

> I had the same problem using tmux 1.8, iTerm2, and
>   reattach-to-user-namespace. I ran across a tmux config binding that
>   fixes the problem: it explicitly copies the last buffer selection to
>   the clipboard:
>
> bind-key q run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace
>   pbcopy"
>
> Put it in your ~/.tmux.conf, and then C-b q will pull everything into
>   your clipboard after a selection.